# Problem on conditional probability and kurtosis.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $[−1,1]$. Given $U$, let $Z$ be a normal random variable with mean $U$ and variance $1$. Prove that $Z$ is not a normal random variable by showing that its kurtosis differs from that of a normal random variable.

I didn’t quite understand how to use given $U$, let $Z$… I guess that mean $E[Z｜U]=U$，$Var[Z|U]=1$ and $Z|U$ is normal. But I want to calculate $\text{kurt}[Z]$. I need $E[Z^4]$ and so on. How could I use these conditions to solve it?

Comment: I suppose, "Kurtosis" means [this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis). So much for English Greek.

Comment: "let Z be a normal random variable with mean U". That looks a lot like a typo. I'm guessing they meant "let Z be a normal random variable with mean $0$".

Answer (score 1):

To compute the expectations necessary to calculate the kurtosis, we can use the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) of conditional expectations, $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Y\left|U\right.\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]$ for any integrable random variable.

Using the tower property, we have for the mean, $\mathbb{E}\left[Z\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Z\left|U\right.\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[U\right] = 0$ and for the variance,
$$\text{Var}\left(Z\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[Z^2\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Z^2\left|U\right.\right]\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\text{Var}\left(Z\left|U\right.\right) + \mathbb{E}\left[Z\left|U\right.\right]^2\right] = 1 + \mathbb{E}\left[U^2\right] = \frac{4}{3}.$$
With these computations, we can calculate the [expectation defining kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis). We write $\mu$ for the mean and $\sigma^2$ the variance,
$$\text{Kurt}\left[Z\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{Z - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^4\right] = \frac{9}{16}\mathbb{E}\left[Z^4\right]=\frac{9}{16}\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[Z^4\left|U\right.\right]\right] = \frac{9}{16}\mathbb{E}\left[U^4 + 6U^2 + 3\right] = 2.925, $$
the second to last equality is the [fourth moment of a normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments).

Comment: I suppose answer also should be times $\frac{9}{16} $?

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Thank you for catching that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct -- $Z$ is ***conditionally normal***, but its unconditional distribution will be more dispersed.

First, note that $\text{Kurt}\left({Z|U=u}\right) = 3 \;\;\forall u$ since $Z|U$ is normally distributed for $U=u$

Given the symmetry of $U$ and $Z|U$, we know that $E[Z]=0$. We can also get this from the properties of conditional expectation $E[Z] = E[E[Z|U]] = E[U] = 0 = \mu_Z$

By the definition of kurtosis, we get:

$$\text{Kurt}\left({Z}\right) :=\frac{E\left[(Z-\mu_Z)^4\right]}{\sigma^4} = \frac{E\left[Z^4\right]}{\sigma^4}=\frac{E[Z^4]}{1}=E[E[Z^4|U]]= $$ $$E\left[{\displaystyle U ^{4}+6U^{2}+3}\right] = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{6}{3} +3 = 5.2 \neq 3$$